# How to print V in c programming in 10X10 row and column in a optimized way?

Tags: c, if-statement, optimization

I printed V using `*` in specific rows and columns. I had lots of `if` statements. I am sharing my code below.

Is there any optimised way to print the V pattern in 10X10 row column? (without many `if` conditions)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int row, column;
    for (row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
        for (column = 1; column <= 10; column++) {
            if (row == 1 && (column == 1 || column == 10)
             || row == 3 && (column == 2 || column == 9)
             || row == 5 && (column == 3 || column == 8)
             || row == 7 && (column == 4 || column == 7)
             || row == 10 && column == 5)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*Is there any optimised way*. Yes there is. Work out the mathematical relation between the current row and the one or two columns where the stars need to be printed. Start off just by writing out the row and column numbers and see if you can then spot the relation.

Comment: @SupportUkraine U have any doubt or confusion..... I don't understand why there is a question mark...

Comment: @SupportUkraine thank you for correcting me. My idea is that if it is a 10X10 matrix, then I thought the dots should be in the 10th row and the 10th column. If not then there is no use of 10X10 matric. The task I saw in the book was to print V in this matric. That's why I was confused.

Comment: Optimizing console output is bizarre. It makes my bones cold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is optimized but will be simpler and scalable with SIZE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
#define MID ((SIZE-1)/2)                // midst position of SIZE
#define ABS(x) ((x)<0?-(x):(x))         // absolute value of x

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && ABS(j - MID) == MID - i / 2) putchar('*');
            else putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**[Explanation]**
Assuming `SIZE` equals to 10, the value `MID` is calculated to be 4.
Then the `v` shaped asterisks will be placed symmetrically wrt the 4th column.
Let's put numbers in columns (j) and rows (i) as follows:

```
012345678
*       * 0   ABS(0 - 4) == 4 - 0, ABS(8 - 4) == 4 - 0
          1   skipped as i & 2 != 0
 *     *  2   ABS(1 - 4) == 4 - 1, ABS(7 - 4) == 4 - 1
          3   skipped
  *   *   4   ABS(2 - 4) == 4 - 2, ABS(6 - 4) == 4 - 2
          5   skipped
   * *    6   ABS(3 - 4) == 4 - 3, ABS(5 - 4) == 4 - 3
          7   skipped
    *     8   ABS(4 - 4) == 4 - 4
```

The equations above are the conditions to put the asterisks.
For instance, in the 0th row, we want to put it on 0th column and 8th.
The condition `j - 4 == +/- 4` or `ABS(j - 4) == 4` will represent the conditions due to the symmetricity.
If we generarize the condition across rows, we can describe it as
`i % 2 == 0 && ABS(j - MID) == MID - i / 2`.

Comment: I find it hard to understand the logic, as I am a beginner. Can u tell me how it works?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer with an explanation. Hope it will help.

Comment: @tshionio Thank you so much for the explanation. It is very precise and neat. Thank u so much for the response.

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable option when you need to output arbitrary amounts of spaces is to use `printf` string width specifier to left-pad with spaces:

```
printf("%*s*", spaces, "");
```

The above will output the empty string, padded up to a width of the integer value `spaces`, and then output a `*`. Note that the format string `%*s` means that you specify both a width and then a string as extra arguments. The `*` in that part has nothing to do with an *actual* `*`. We add *that* onto the end of the format string.

So, for the V shape, each line has two `*` characters on it, except the last line (if the width is odd). One way to do this intuitively is to track the position of the left and the right part of the V for each line, and then do the math for determining how much padding to add.

Example:

```
void v(int width)
{
    int l = 0, r = width;
    for (; l < r; l++, r--)
    {
        printf("%*s*%*s\n", l, "", r-l, "*");
    }
    if (l == r)
        printf("%*s*\n", l, "");
}
```

If you really want more condensed code, you can elect to roll that last line into the loop. In this case, when `l == r` you want to only output a single asterisk. Otherwise you want two. So you could output the string `&"*"[l==r]` -- that will mean that when `l==r` is true, you'll skip over the asterisk and it will look like an empty string (because you land on the NUL terminator).

Note this is not great style. It sacrifices readability for compactness.

```
void v(int width)
{
    for (int l = 0, r = width; l <= r; l++, r--)
    {
        printf("%*s*%*s\n", l, "", r-l, &"*"[l==r]);
    }
}
```

So, this is "efficient" in terms of compact code and not many function calls. If you instead are concerned about the format parsing of `printf` then you can avoid it entirely. Below, we use the same left/right bounds and just walk through each row using loops. This essentially does what our `printf` is doing internally, except it's more obvious what's going on:

```
void v(int width)
{
    int l = 0, r = width-1;
    for (; l <= r; l++, r--)
    {
        int x = 0;
        for (; x < l; x++) putchar(' ');
        putchar('*');
        if (x < r)
        {
            for (x++; x < r; x++) putchar(' ');
            putchar('*');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

---

Now for some fun...

As an exercise, here is the `printf` approach but with no loops (using recursion):

```
void vv(int width, int row) {
    if(width >= 0) {
        printf("%*s*%*s\n", row, "", width, &"*"[width==0]);
        vv(width-2, row+1);
    }
}

void v(int width) {
    vv(width, 0);
}
```

And here is *that* idea turned into an intentionally horrendous mess that looks cool. ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VV int
#define vV "*\0%*s%*s\n"

VV Vv( VV     v ,VV
 vv){if(v    -->0){
  printf     (vV+2,
   vv++     ,vV,v
   ,vV+     !v);
    Vv(--  v,vv
     );}} VV V
      (VV v){
       Vv(v,
        1);
         }

int main() {
    for (int v = 1; v < 12; v++) {
        printf("size %d\n", v);
        V(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code considers the relation between the row and the position of the *, if you are in the first row, then we want the column 0 and colum 9 to print *, then second row, we want column 1 and column 8 and so on. Thus, I used an iterator for the rows and iterator for columns to know in a concrete row which column I'm printing.

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int matrix_size = 10; //Assuming is squared matrix 10x10
    int counter = 0;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<(int)(matrix_size/2);i++) {
        for(j=0;j<matrix_size;j++) {
            if(j==i || j==(matrix_size-1-i)) {
                printf("*");
            }else{
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: compared to tshiono solution, I write the V in just 5 rows and he prints it in 10 rows but assuming an space line between each line. Boths solutions are ok depending on what u want.

Answer (score 1):

For the V shape to be symmetric, the number of rows and columns should be odd. Here is a simpler method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    for (int n = 11, row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < n; column++)
            putchar(" *"[2 * abs(column - n / 2) == n - 1 - row]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*         *

 *       *

  *     *

   *   *

    * *

     *
```

For a thicker V shape:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    for (int n = 11, row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < n; column++)
            putchar(" *"[abs(2 * abs(column - n / 2) - (n - 1 - row)) <= 1]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*         *
**       **
 *       *
 **     **
  *     *
  **   **
   *   *
   ** **
    * *
    ***
     *
```

Comment: The code works excellently. But as a beginner, I cant understand your code. What is that "abs"? Like can u explain to me the putchar line alone? The logic behind that line.

Comment: @Harsha: the `abs` function defined in `<stdlib.h>` takes an `int` and returns its absolute value as an `int`. I shall amend the answer with an explanation later today.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers take into account the specific shape of V and optimize around that.

I suggest an optimized solution for any shape.

This involves a lookup table containing all the locations of `*` characters composing the shape.

```
struct { int row,col; } shape[] = {
   {1,1}, {1,10}, {3,2}, {3,9}, {5,3}, {5,8}, {7,4}, {7,7}, {10,5},
   {-1,-1}
};
```

The last location (`{-1,-1}`) has the same purpose as terminating `'\0'` for strings.

Comment: Hey, this program is not working in my Visual studio code compiler and code chef compiler. Like it is executed successfully but nothing is seen in output screen